# Unity negative feedback controller, why does Gain K go on the numerator of the transfer function

Tags: transfer-function, feedback, laplace-transform, unity-gain

I have a system G(s). It has no zeroes, but some poles.

When applying unity negative feedback, with a static gain K, why does K remain on the numerator of my transfer function T(s) which describes the whole closed loop system?

If I have no zeroes, Z(s), then surely K multiplied by Z(s) is 0? But it is K.

In addition, in the denominator, there is another term that is again, K multiplied by Z(s). No zeroes, but this term simplifies to K, and not 0.

I understand that Z(s) is a function, and normally takes the form (s+3)(s+1) or something, but if there are no zeroes, can someone explain why K remains on the numerator?

Thanks

[image: Example]

Comment: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Control_Systems/Block_Diagrams#Simplifying_Block_Diagrams, i'm unsure of your question

Comment: K doesn't have any zeroes.

Comment: No zeros means \$Z(s)=1\$, hence \$K Z(s)=K\$

Answer (score 1):

The order of the Tf goes from its highest power down to s^0 which is one ie theres always a one there